# AddXY points in a chart, Y point is shown but is not labeled

Tags: c#, graph, mschart

I want to show a graph with exactly the assigned values for Y axis, however after running the program, it shows some sequences like 20,40,60, etc.

Even if I've a y value of 30 for instance, it draws it but with no label on Y.

Here is the code

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Time (MS)";
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Algorithm Used";
this.chart1.Series["SURF"].Points.AddXY(1, SURFT/1000);
this.chart1.Series["SURF Sensor"].Points.AddXY(1, SURFSensorT / 1000);
this.chart1.Series["SIFT"].Points.AddXY(2, SIFT/1000);
this.chart1.Series["SIFT Sensor"].Points.AddXY(2, SIFTSensorT / 1000);
this.chart1.Series["BRISK"].Points.AddXY(3, BRISKT/1000);
this.chart1.Series["BRISK Sensor"].Points.AddXY(3, BRISKSensorT/1000);
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite normal; image the clutter if all y-values would be labelled at the y-axis. You can turn on datapoint labels, though.. You can also control the interval of the labels. Or you could replace them by customlabels.

Comment: Thanks for replaying, there are good tricks especially the one with the cutomlabels for them, however I need to display them on the Y-axis rather than on top of each bar.

Comment: CustomLabels are displayed along either one of the Axes. Note that they are tricky, as they are placed centered between __two__ values